# SSL Socket in Android and HTTP

Tags: android, sslsocketfactory

I am trying to send image string from android to server using NamePairValues. It is working fine with http but not with Https. Using Https my code shows error responce on mobile app:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x12ad700: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

Please help me how to solve this issue . I have used exact same code that is used for SSL layers. I have used SSL Socket Factory generic class. Here is the code fragment.

Here are calling lines from App.

```
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", sendImages));
                   // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "L0"));
                    pBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
                    pBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    pBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    pBar.setMessage("Communication With Server, Authenticating...");
                    pBar.show();

                    MyAsyncTask1 mTask = new MyAsyncTask1();

                    mTask.setOnResultsListener(this);

                    mTask.execute(myURL
                            , nameValuePairs);
```

here is a class to execute task

```
public class MyAsyncTask1 extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {

    ResultsListener listener;


    public void setOnResultsListener(ResultsListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String res = null;
        DefaultHttpClient responseBody = null;
        if (params.length > 0) {
            String mUrl =  params[0].toString();
            List<NameValuePair> mParams = (List<NameValuePair>) params[1];

            //String pam = "param1="+"dsd"+"&param2="+mobile+"&param3=" + "sds"+"&param4="+"sdsds"+"&param5="+"dsds"+"&param6="+Images;
            //String regx = "[] ";
            //char[] ca = regx.toCharArray();
            //for (char c : ca) {
              //  pam = pam.replace(""+c, "");
               // pam = pam.replace(",", "&");

          //  }

            try{

                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                trustStore.load(null, null);

                MySSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);

                 SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
                    registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));


                socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(socketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);


                DefaultHttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();              
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(registry);
                HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(mUrl);
                 httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(mParams));
            //  System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                //System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                //System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                //if (entity != null) {
                //   System.out.println("Response content length:  " + entity.getContentLength());
                //}

                // Print html.
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    res=line; 
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                in.close();

                }catch(Exception e){

                    return res=e.toString();

                }

            }
        return res;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (!listener.equals(null)) {
            listener.onResultsSucceeded(result);
        }
    }

    public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);

            sf.setHostnameVerifier(MySSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you did a getNewHttpClient () method for your httpclient and not using?

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();              
...
```

Try something like this:

```
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    httpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) getNewHttpClient();

    HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(mUrl);
    httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(mParams));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        res = line;
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    return res = e.toString();
}
```